# Twitter API rate limit passed because of admob

Tags: android, twitter, admob, twitter4j

I'm facing a problem in my Android application based on twitter api with twitter4j.

I v'e got the usual error of passing the rate limit. **this problem appears only when i use code that contains requesting an ad from admob**.

*`"Returned in API v1.1 when a request cannot be served due to the application's rate limit having been exhausted for the resource."`*

When i comment the admob code the problem disappear, i couldn't figure out what the source of this issue.

this is how i call my ad in `onCreate` method:
this how my code's looks like:

```
AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
adView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
AdRequest adResquest = new AdRequest();
adView.loadAd(adResquest);
```

and this is how i simply use my twitter object from twitter4j:

first authenticate to twitter:

```
private Twitter authenticateToTwitter() {
        ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        configurationBuilder.setDebugEnabled(true);
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);
        configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
        Configuration configuration = configurationBuilder.build();
        twitter = new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance();

        return twitter;
}
```

then call my twitter object and use it:

```
final Paging paging = new Paging(1, 100);       
        try {
            List<Status> statuses = getTwitter().getUserTimeline(paging);
            for (Status status : statuses) {
                Database.insert(status);//inserting statuses into database

            }

        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
        }
```

Comment: You don't say where, when or how you are invoking your Twitter code.

Comment: the only call ive made is when call usertimeline
this problem only apears when i uncomment my admob code

Comment: I could not find any relationship between twitter and admob, but according to you, somehow admob uses the auth token and you get rate limit issue because more than one place you are accessing twitter with one token.